# Office UI Fabric ReactJS Dropdown Accessibility issue

Tags: accessibility, dropdown, office-ui-fabric

I am using Office UI Fabric Dropdown in React.js. I am testing the application for accessibility issues using Keros for Web.

It is showing this issue for dropdowns:

```
aria-valid-attr-value: ARIA attributes must conform to valid values
Fix the following: Invalid ARIA attribute value: aria-labelledby="usercountryRegion-label" 
Snippet: <div data-is-focusable="true" id="usercountryRegion" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="usercountryRegion-label" aria-describedby="usercountryRegion-option" aria-activedescendant="usercountryRegion-option" name="country" class="ms-Dropdown root_aecb6435">
```

I searched for some answer and all I got is "Ensure the value inside each attribute is spelled correctly and corresponds to a valid value.", but I could not find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Search your code for "usercountryRegion-label".  The value of `aria-labelledby` must be the **ID** of another object.  Make sure the ID attribute (**not** the NAME attribute) is "usercountryRegion-label" of the element you're pointing to.

**Good:**

```html
<div id="usercountryRegion-label">Africa</div>
```

**Bad:**

```html
<div name="usercountryRegion-label">Africa</div>
```

Comment: We are not able to override the aria-labelledby attribute since it is coming from office fabric drop down component,if you have any other approach that will be helpful for us.

Comment: I'm not asking you to change the `aria-labelledby`.  I'm saying whatever value the `aria-labelledby` is showing, it needs to be a valid **ID** of another object.  If the object it points to only has a **NAME** attribute and not an **ID** attribute, that would cause the error.